# Common template for Joomla + Wordpress + phpBB or Drupal + Wordpress + phpBB

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, joomla, phpbb

I'm struggling to try and find an answer to this question and was hoping someone might be able to help me.

Are there any common/easy editable themes that I can use across Joomla (or Drupal), Wordpress and phpBB?  I know that you can find decent forum and blogging modules in both Joomla and Drupal but I want to stay with Wordpress and phpBB (mainly because of the LaTeX support).

I've got my Joomla site up and running using the JA Purity II template but have spent absolutely ages trying to get the header set up right on my phpBB forums.  I don't really fancy putting the same effort in with Wordpress updating it every time I update my header.  There must be an easier way!  BTW I like Purity II because of the configurable megamenu it uses...

I can't believe anyone hasn't asked this question already.  Are there any consistent themes I can use across all three applications?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can take any theme and put it in any system. The problem is they all use different ways of templating. phptemplate, smarty, raw php, etc templating methods. I don't think there are any that are truely plug in play due to this difference.

You can use the HTML structure though, and create a baseline for Drupal, Wordpress and Joomla by replacing the PHP calls with their correct counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Sandbox theme is available across Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla. PhpBB will be hard to pattern against that since that's a bb though.

Granted it won't be coded in the same way (afaik), because Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla are structured differently, but Sandbox is a base designers' theme, so you could just customize it, and your customizations should be fairly easy to cascade through your other systems.